# measurement range of tdc

Tags: converter, texas-instruments

While going through some datasheets of  tdc's (time to digital converter ) there is this parameter which is called 'measurement range', could someone please explain what exactly it is? If the measurement range of a certain tdc state "0 to 40 us", does this mean the measurement range is inclusive of 'ns' too?

Answer (score 1):

The [TDC7200 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tdc7200.pdf) specifies:

> (p1) Measurement Range:
>   – Mode 1: 12 ns to 500 ns
>   – Mode 2: 250 ns to 8 ms

and

```
(p5)
+-----------------+------------------------------+-----+-----+------+------+
|      Param      |         Description          | min | typ | max  | unit |
+-----------------+------------------------------+-----+-----+------+------+
| T1STARTSTOP_Min | t_min between Start and Stop |  12 |     | ns   |      |
| T1STOPSTOP_Min  | t_min between 2 Stop Signals |  67 |     | ns   |      |
| T1STARTSTOP_Max | t_max between Start and Stop |     | 500 | ns   |      |
+-----------------+------------------------------+-----+-----+------+------+
```

table adapted from datasheet, formatted thanks to [online tool](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/)

So you can see that for mode 1 the range is defined as t_min between Start and Stop up to t_max between Start and Stop.

Within those boundaries the measurement will be returned with a resolution:

> (p1) Resolution: 55 ps

So from a high-level timing longer than 12ns and shorter than 500ns can be measured with a resolution of 55ps (in mode 1), for mode 2 this is a function of the SPI clock provided to the TDC.

Answer (score 0):

Measurement range is the range of time intervals the converter can measure. It can't measure a time interval less than the minimum time, nor a time interval greater than the maximum time. If the time interval you want to measure is within the specified range, the converter will be able to measure it.

The measurement resolution is a separate parameter. This specifies whether the converter can measure down to the nearest nS, or better. It should be listed elsewhere on the data sheet.

Think of it like this - a 30cm long ruler has a measurement range of 0-30cm. If it only has 1cm markings, then it will only be able to measure at a resolution of 1cm. If it has 0.1cm markings, then it will be able to measure at a resolution of 0.1cm. These two parameters (range and resolution) are separate quantities.